# Python tkinter.ttk theme_create parent theme "clam" doesn't affect Buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, button, ttk

In Python when using ttk you can give a parent theme in `theme_create()` and then change the theme to your liking. When I give the parent "clam" I expect the buttons to be a beige color until I change the values in `theme_settings()` but instead it is just a white square with the text in the middle. The lack of applied theme is really odd as other widgets like the ttk.Notebook have the theme. Any thoughts? (On MacOSX)

I tried searching for answers but nothing came up on google for this and only four StackOverflow questions have ever mentioned `theme_create()` and of those none touch this problem.

Some sample code is attached:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Style

root = Tk()

style = Style()
style.theme_create("user_theme", parent="clam")
style.theme_use("user_theme")
#style.theme_use("clam") #Affects Buttons and all other widgets but shouldn't the parent apply clam to all widgets until changed?

btn = Button(root, text="Button")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Photo of the window](https://ibb.co/tqzT1Bm)

NOTE:

When using the `clam` theme on it's own using `style.theme_use("clam")` it does affect buttons meaning that this bug is indeed specific to `theme_create()`

Comment: I have been able to reproduce it in Windows, with tkinter version 8.6.12

Comment: I realized this is due to the fact that the clam theme uses C drawing code for many widgets so it's unable to transfer it.